# Find similar words for bigrams using nltk.similar

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, similarity

I want to find similar words from the corpus of text using [nltk.similar](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text.similar) function. However this function does not work for bigrams like `angular momentum`. I can not even use other similarity metrics like `wup_similarity` etc. So how can I find similar words for bigrams?

Note that - `nltk.similar` uses context of a given word (previous + next words) to find similar words.

Comment: Try `gensim` https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html